# Zope external file or static resource directory

Tags: firebase, webpack, plone, zope

I integrated a JavaScript app built with webpack into an instance of Zope 2.13.26. I added the files manually but now I want to link the app's folder in Zope with the /public folder used by webpack on the file system.

The reason for this is that whenever I redeploy the app with webpack, all 89 of the JS and CSS files are recreated, making it impractical to update the app in Zope.

In some older Zopes I still have, for example 2.10, it would be possible to use the old ExternalFile product to access a directory on the file system but more recent versions of Zope lack the Zope 2 style interfaces so I tried to adapt the ExternalFile product by changing IExternalFile.py from:

```
from Interface import Base
```

to:

```
from zope.interface import Interface
```

which allowed Zope to start, but I still can't add an ExternalFile. I get this error:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 138, in publish
  Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
  Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 48, in call_object
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 322, in __call__
  Module Shared.DC.Scripts.Bindings, line 359, in _bindAndExec
  Module Products.PageTemplates.PageTemplateFile, line 130, in _exec
  Module Products.PageTemplates.PageTemplate, line 87, in pt_render
  Module zope.pagetemplate.pagetemplate, line 132, in pt_render
  Module five.pt.engine, line 98, in __call__
  Module z3c.pt.pagetemplate, line 163, in render
  Module chameleon.zpt.template, line 261, in render
  Module chameleon.template, line 191, in render
  Module chameleon.template, line 171, in render
  Module a92620f1f1dd7213a9d78f8af1772eb6.py, line 383, in render
  Module five.pt.expressions, line 135, in __call__
  Module five.pt.expressions, line 126, in traverse
  Module zope.traversing.adapters, line 136, in traversePathElement
   - __traceback_info__: (<App.ProductContext.__FactoryDispatcher__ object at 0x7f3b5e4b8290>, 'gethostname')
  Module zope.traversing.adapters, line 50, in traverse
   - __traceback_info__: (<App.ProductContext.__FactoryDispatcher__ object at 0x7f3b5e4b8290>, 'gethostname', ())
LocationError: (<App.ProductContext.__FactoryDispatcher__ object at 0x7f3b5e4b8290>, 'gethostname')

 - Expression: "container/gethostname"
 - Filename:   create
 - Location:   (line 37: col 20)
 - Arguments:  repeat: {...} (0)
               template: <ImplicitAcquisitionWrapper create at 0x7f3b605a9be0>
               modules: <instance - at 0x7f3b677e3098>
               here: <ImplicitAcquisitionWrapper - at 0x7f3b605a9140>
               user: <ImplicitAcquisitionWrapper - at 0x7f3b605a93c0>
               nothing: <NoneType - at 0x8f5320>
               container: <ImplicitAcquisitionWrapper - at 0x7f3b605a9140>
               basedir: 
               default: <object - at 0x7f3b6f875540>
               request: <instance - at 0x7f3b5fa20b48>
               wrapped_repeat: <SafeMapping - at 0x7f3b5fb1f2b8>
               loop: {...} (0)
               context: <ImplicitAcquisitionWrapper - at 0x7f3b605a9140>
               translate: <function translate at 0x7f3b5d81bcf8>
               root: <ImplicitAcquisitionWrapper Zope at 0x7f3b605a9640>
               options: {...} (1)
               target_language: <NoneType - at 0x8f5320>
```

I don't understand the error and I don't know if this approach can be made to work at all.

I also looked into the Plone "static resource directory" way of doing this, but I do not see where to register the directory. My index_html is a plain HTML file (not a page template) and the ++resource++ format could be a problem because the main JS file calls other files that need to be in standard locations.

Otherwise, the app works and I would love to add some modern functionality to this legacy site. Any solutions appreciated!

Comment: I linked to your question from https://community.plone.org/t/zope-external-file-or-static-resource-directory/7628 but generally you'll get faster/better replies if you post there directly.